# Passing $_GET to a function inside a class inside an include file

Tags: php, include, get

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you use $_GET variables when including a file in PHP? Is it possible, even from an AJAX call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163262/can-you-use-get-variables-when-including-a-file-in-php-is-it-possible-even-f)

I have function within a class that I include but my profile page's $_GET doesn't pass the variable to the function inside the class, inside the include file.

Comment: Also, I should note that I'm doing everything on MAMP.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you're trying to do. Can you try to elaborate?

Comment: What is your question? You include files, not pages. $_GET is a superglobal and is available everywhere. What is the problem?

Comment: Maybe post some code, and explain what you've tried.

Comment: 10 hours of searchign for you, 5 seconds for me here on SO... I think your google-fu needs some improvement.

Comment: Sure, I have a profile.php page that uses $_GET to collect a simple member_id, once I have the member_id, I render the profile page with no problem [ex: profile.php?member_id=4]. My problem is passing this member_id to an include file that defines various functions that need to use this member_id...Does that make sense at all?

Comment: You don't pass variables to an included file.

Comment: I have function within a class that I include but my profile page's $_GET doesn't pass the variable to the function inside the class, inside the include file.

Comment: The included file has access to any variables in the scope from which it was included... But since the value youre looking for is in `$_GET` just use `$_GET` it is super global and available in all scopes.

Comment: Then pass it as an argument... that is the proper way... you should be using vars that are not members of the class or passed in as arguments to one oe of its methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$member_id = (integer) $_GET['member_id'];
include('TheClass.php');
$obj = new TheClass();
$obj->doSomething($member_id);
```

If you need the value when you you construct the class then pass it to the constructor:

```
$member_id = (integer) $_GET['member_id'];
include('TheClass.php');
$obj = new TheClass($member_id);
$obj->doSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

on the included page...

```
if ($_GET['var']){
    functionhere($_GET['var']);

}
```